# Zabbix monitor http service with simple check

Tags: linux, http, zabbix

How can I add trigger, or to be correct .. how should trigger look like,  for net.tcp.service[http,80]  so it would sound alarm if http is down   longer than minute or two. I know that I can set interval in which zabbix would check if http is present  and it will return 0 if http is down and 1 if it up. So let say that after checking 3 times each time http sent 0 ( it was down). How to add trigger for this?

Also, I heard that it's possible to make load graphs  for http using zabbix? Anyone know how to do it or have link to some good how to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How can I add trigger so it would sound alarm if triggered longer than minute or two

A: You mean, more downtime in last period of time, then trigger will look like this:

With average value:

`{net.tcp.service[http,80].avg(120)}<0,5`

Or with `count`:

`{net.tcp.service[http,80].count(120)}<60`

Or maybe you want to see only pure constant downtime? OK:

`{net.tcp.service[http,80].count(120)}<1`

--

Q: Let say that after checking 3 times each time http sent 0 ( it was down). How to add trigger for this?

A: `{net.tcp.service[http,80].count(#3)}<1`

--

Q?: I heard that it's possible to make load graphs for http using zabbix? Anyone know how to do it or have link to some good how to ?

A: At first, you must evaluate what "load graph for http" means technically: CPU load, CPU usage, RAM usage, connection usage etc. there is no such thing called "http load" :)

--

Note: net.tcp.service won't check is your site working or not or is service working fine or not, it's just establishing TCP connection and simple HTTP session. For better availability check use [Zabbix Web Monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/web_monitoring).